# Suggestion for an ISO image indexer and manager?

Tags: search, iso

I have recently moved from Windows to Linux and my most missed application is WhereIsIt.

I am looking for a software that can index the contents of all my ISO files (750GB in total) sitting in an external hard drive. The goal is to search for old files that were backed up in the ISO files over the years. Is there any good application for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low-cost solution: for each ISO, generate the list of files by running `find` from the ISO's toplevel directory. Either do it before generating the ISO, or from an image:

```
mkdir mnt
for iso in *.iso; do
  fuseiso "$iso" mnt &&
  (cd mnt && find) >"$iso.find" &&
  fusermount -u "$iso"
done
```

Then, when you're looking for a file whose name contains `foo`:

```
grep foo *.find
```